# Price display different after selecting attribute

Tags: price

I have a problem, in first the price displays as x,xxx.xx then when i select an attribute it changes to x.xxx,xx. Can anybody help me figure it out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could try to change the local settings.
- So go to your magento directory and open the file
  lib/Zend/Local/Data/en.xml (replace en.xml by the language file for
  which you would like to perform your changes).
- Search for

`<numbers>
    <symbols>
        <decimal>.</decimal>
        <group>,</group>`

Clear the cache, also for safer side please try to do this first on your test installation to avoid issues.